# css3 hover effect not working on firefox

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser, hover

I am working on a css based hover effects. However the effects are perfectly working in chrome but  not in firefox version 26. here's the
 http://jsfiddle.net/gfxbucket/Bz3E8
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
/* Caption Style 4 */
.team-grid li {
    -webkit-perspective: 1700px;
       -moz-perspective: 1700px;
            perspective: 1700px;
    -webkit-perspective-origin: 0 50%;
       -moz-perspective-origin: 0 50%;
            perspective-origin: 0 50%;
}

.team-grid figure {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
       -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.team-grid figure > div {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.team-grid figure img {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
       -moz-transition:    -moz-transform 0.4s;
            transition:         transform 0.4s;
}

.no-touch .team-grid figure:hover img,
.team-grid figure.cs-hover img {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(25%);
       -moz-transform: translateX(25%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(25%);
            transform: translateX(25%);
}

.team-grid figcaption {
    height: 100%;
    width: 60%;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
       -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
       -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
            transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
       -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
            transform: rotateY(-90deg);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s 0.3s;
       -moz-transition:    -moz-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s 0.3s;
            transition:         transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s 0.3s;
}

.no-touch .team-grid figure:hover figcaption,
.team-grid figure.cs-hover figcaption {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
       -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
            transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s;
       -moz-transition:    -moz-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s;
            transition:         transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s;
}
```

Comment: Hover effects are working perfectly for me. Firefox 25, Linux.

Comment: And works also in firefox 26 OSX (mac)

Comment: You could try to use this plugin for CSS3 animations: http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Comment: @wei2912 it's weird, I'm a windows user. it's not working out for me. After checking out the comment section for this effect i saw many others also facing this problem. Any suggestion why? http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/18/caption-hover-effects/

Comment: I think firefox 26 is beta version .That's why may comes problem!Download latest version stable

Answer (score 1):

Well your fiddle works perfect on my FF26 Mac.

Although, you're missing a closing / on the img in the html. Could that have something to do with it if your're running an xhtml strict doctype maybe?

Best of luck!